# How do I make a new label every time in a loop in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So let's say that every time I run a loop, I want to make a new label in Tkinter. I don't know how to do that, and that's been a roadblock to a project I am making.

```
import tkinter as tk
wndw= tk.Tk()
wndw.configure(background="white")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(wndw, width = 500, height = 500)
canvas1.pack()
for i in range(0,10):
    #over here I want to continuously make a label(which is distinct from 
    #the last one)until the loop is finished
```

Though I know that in this case, I can manually make 10 different labels, I need to be able to make them automatically for the project I am doing.

Please keep in mind that I am using Tkinter. If there is any way to do this, I would be very grateful if you told me how to.

Answer (score 0):

```
labels = {}
for i in range(10):
    labels[i] = tk.Label(text="Label %d" % i)
    labels[i].pack()
```

This will give you a distinct set of labels. Just insert the above in lieu of your `for` loop.

The above stores the label objects in a dict, so you can access them easily enough. And because each label's text includes its index number, each label is unique.

If you don't need to store the label objects, you can shorten the above to:

```
for i in range(10):
    tk.Label(text="Label %d" % i).pack()
```

Labels, like most Tkinter widgets, take a `text` keyword, via which you can define the text displayed on the widget.